# JavaFX webengine.executeScript as first line of code, runs at the end of the code

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

I need to take a snapshot of a very long page. I want to take multiple screenshots and put them together luggage. to move the view I am using a javascript to do scrolling.

these functions:

```
private ArrayList<BufferedImage> takeSnapshots (int numRows, int numCols){
     ArrayList<BufferedImage> snapshotsList = new ArrayList ();
    for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<numCols; j++){
            forward ((BASE_WIDTH*j), (BASE_HEIGHT*i));
            WritableImage snapshot = webView.snapshot(null, null);
            snapshotsList .add (SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot , null));
        }
    }
    return snapshotsList ;
}

private void  forward (int widht, int height ){
    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webEngine.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + widht+ ", " + height + ")");
}
```

this code returns me a list of screenshots of the first chunk and at the end do scrolling. Any ideas to fix?